# How do I fill the first empty TextBox in a GroupBox?

Tags: vb.net

I have a `GroupBox` with multiple `TextBox` controls and I can check to see if any are empty just fine but I'm trying to make my program fill the first empty textbox it finds in the `GroupBox`.

Code:

```
Dim empty = From txt In grpbill.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)() 
            Where txt.Text.Length = 0 

If empty.Any Then 

End If
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. I'm unsure on how you define *first* but I've gone off the `TabIndex` property:

```
Dim firstEmptyTextBox As TextBox = (From txt In GroupBox1.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
                                    Where txt.Text.Length = 0
                                    Order By txt.TabIndex Ascending).FirstOrDefault()

If firstEmptyTextBox IsNot Nothing Then
    firstEmptyTextBox.Text = "Text"
End If
```

You can use the [.FirstOrDefault()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

> Returns the first element of a sequence, or a default value if the sequence contains no elements.

In my example I have three `TextBox` controls. The first one has the text *Not empty* whilst the other two have nothing. When I run the code, this is my output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here another idea which will also work in cases where all `TextBox` controls in `GroupBox` are not empty.

```
Private Sub SetTextJForFirstEmptyTextBoxIfExists(text As String)

    Dim emptyTextBoxes As IEnumerable(Of TextBox) 
        = grpbill.Controls.
                  OfType(Of TextBox)().
                  Where(Function(txtbox) txtbox.Text.Length = 0)

    For Each emptyTextBox In emptyTextBoxes
        emptyTextBox.Text = text
        Exit Sub
    Next
End Sub
```